# Should I use only one Ractive instance or many?

Tags: ractivejs

I'm building a mobile app that have many panels and I was wondering if it's a good idea (in regards of performance, memory use, code size and ease of maintainability) to have one Ractive instance by panel or if it's preferable to have only one Ractive instance for the whole application? I'm leaning towards many instances for ease of maintainability but I really don't know how it will affect performance and memory use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overhead for creating additional instances is very small - it's only really if you're creating hundreds or thousands of instances (whether directly, or as inline [components](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/components)) that you might find you need to optimise things.

So in general I'd advise writing the application in the way that's most maintainable. If you *did* find that performance was a problem, then depending on the nature of your app you might find a happy medium between having a single instance for the entire thing, and dividing it too finely.